# T-SQL Two counts with different where clause

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I want to count values on a table with different where clauses and wondering if there is a better way of doing it.

In this code i count one value.

```
SELECT v.name, count(v.value) AS v1
FROM dbo.table as v
WHERE v.organisationID = 2
AND v.datecreated > '2018-01-01'
AND v.datecreated < '2018-05-01'
AND v.value = 1
GROUP BY v.name
```

I also want to count all rows with value = 2
my way of doing it is like this with a sub select.

```
SELECT v.name, count(v.value) AS v1, (SELECT v2.name, count(v2.value)  
FROM dbo.table as v2
WHERE v2.organisationID = 2
AND v2.datecreated > '2018-01-01'
AND v2.datecreated < '2018-05-01'
AND v2.value = 2
GROUP BY v2.name) AS v2
FROM dbo.table as v
WHERE v.organisationID = 2
AND v.datecreated > '2018-01-01'
AND v.datecreated < '2018-05-01'
AND v.value = 1
GROUP BY v.name
```

The table contains > 100 millions rows so I really want the fastest way. I use clustered columnstore index on the table.

Is there some way of doing it whitout sub-select.

Pseudo code:

```
SELECT v.name, count(v.value where v.value=1) AS v1, count(v.value where v.value=2) AS v2
FROM dbo.table as v
WHERE v.organisationID = 2
AND v.datecreated > '2018-01-01'
AND v.datecreated < '2018-05-01'
GROUP BY v.name
```

Comment: Performance depends heavily on the database used. What's fast in one system, isn't necessarily in another. Which one do you use?

Comment: SQL-server 2016 Enterprise

Comment: Does it matter if you get 1 row or two?  If not then group by your organisationID and name where v.organisationID in (1,2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT  v.name, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN v.value = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN v.value = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS v2
FROM dbo.table as v
WHERE v.organisationID = 2
AND v.datecreated > '2018-01-01'
AND v.datecreated < '2018-05-01'
AND v.value IN (1,2)
GROUP BY v.name
;
```